# GPG: Decrypt BLOWFISH encrypted file

Tags: blowfish, gnupg

I have received encrypted files from someone who used something called omziff to encrypt using BLOWFISH cipher. When I try to decrypt this using GPG like so:

```
gpg -d --cipher-algo BLOWFISH file.txt
```

I get the following error message:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof
```

When I query GPG for supported ciphers, I see blowfish in that list:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.11
...
Cipher: 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH, CAMELLIA128, 
    CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Thanks for any pointers.

-Raj

Answer (score 1):

Your file needs to be in PGP format for GPG to recognize it.  It's unlikely you'd be able to decrypt this file using GPG.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I thought the ciphers and file formats were more "standard". I guess this is not the case.

Comment: The ciphers are standard.  How the ciphertext (and related packaging, like IV and other parameters) are expressed in the file is not.